# if statement with Input.GetButtonUp and > 0 doesnt return true

Tags: unity-game-engine

The statement `if(Input.GetButtonUp("Heavy Attack") && chargeTime > 0)` never returns true unless I am mashing heavy attack like a madman and I do not understand why?

```js
    var ID: int = 003;
    var motionCounter: int[];
    var currentMotion: int;
    var timeBetweenButtons: float;
    var chargeTime: float;
    var isComboing: boolean;

    function Awake() {
      timeBetweenButtons = 0;
      motionCounter = new int[10];
      currentMotion = 0;
      chargeTime = 0.7;
      isComboing = false;
    }

    function Update() {
      if (isComboing == true) {
        timeBetweenButtons -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (timeBetweenButtons <= 0) {
          isComboing = false;
          currentMotion = 0;
          motionCounter[0] = 0;
          Debug.Log("Combo Dropped");
        }
      }
      if (currentMotion == 0) {
        if (Input.GetButton("Heavy Attack")) {
          chargeTime -= Time.deltaTime;
          if (chargeTime <= 0) {
            Debug.Log("Lunging Bite");
            chargeTime = 0.7;
          }
          if (Input.GetButtonUp("Heavy Attack") && chargeTime > 0) {
            chargeTime = 0.7;
            motionCounter[currentMotion] = 2;
            timeBetweenButtons = 1;
            Debug.Log("Coiling Rattle");
          }
          if (Input.GetButtonDown("Light Attack")) {
            timeBetweenButtons = 1;
            motionCounter[currentMotion] = 1;
            currentMotion++;
            Debug.Log("Vipers_Tooth_01");
          }
        }
      }
      if (currentMotion > 0) {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Light Attack")) {
          motionCounter[currentMotion] = 1;
          if (motionCounter[currentMotion] == 1 && motionCounter[currentMotion - 1] == 1) {
            timeBetweenButtons = 1;
            Debug.Log("Vipers_Tooth_02");
            currentMotion = 0;
          }
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Heavy Attack")) {
          motionCounter[currentMotion] = 2;
        }
      }
    }
```

```
var motionCounter : int[];
var currentMotion : int;
var timeBetweenButtons : float;
var chargeTime : float;
var isComboing : boolean;

function Awake()
{
    timeBetweenButtons = 0;
    motionCounter = new int[10];
    currentMotion = 0;
    chargeTime = 0.7;
    isComboing = false;
}

function Update()
{
    if(isComboing == true)
    {
    timeBetweenButtons -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(timeBetweenButtons <= 0)
        {
        isComboing = false;
        currentMotion = 0;
        motionCounter[0] = 0;
        Debug.Log("Combo Dropped");
        }
    }
    if(currentMotion == 0)
    {
        if(Input.GetButton("Heavy Attack"))
        {
            chargeTime -= Time.deltaTime;
                if( chargeTime <= 0)
                {
                Debug.Log("Lunging Bite");
                chargeTime = 0.7;
                }
                if(Input.GetButtonUp("Heavy Attack") && chargeTime > 0)
                {
                chargeTime = 0.7;
                motionCounter[currentMotion] = 2;
                timeBetweenButtons = 1;
                Debug.Log("Coiling Rattle");
                }
                if(Input.GetButtonDown("Light Attack"))
                {
                timeBetweenButtons = 1;
                motionCounter[currentMotion] = 1;
                currentMotion++;
                Debug.Log("Vipers_Tooth_01");
                }
        }
    }
    if(currentMotion > 0)
    {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Light Attack"))
        {
        motionCounter[currentMotion] = 1;
            if(motionCounter[currentMotion] == 1 && motionCounter[currentMotion - 1] == 1)
            {
            timeBetweenButtons = 1;
            Debug.Log("Vipers_Tooth_02");
            currentMotion = 0;
            }
        }
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Heavy Attack"))
        {
        motionCounter[currentMotion] = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `GetButtonUp` only occurs when releasing the button. Are you sure you want your `chargeTime` to reset while holding the button down? This means you need to time your release with your `chargeTime` resetting, which probably only occurs within a fraction of a second. If you can create a GUI rectangle and use that as a charge meter, that might help.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the chargeTime but it is intended

Answer (score 0):

If You want charge time to be >0 then why are you doing this?

> chargeTime -= Time.deltaTime;

shouldn't you be increasing your variable to correspond to the number of seconds the player is holding the button?

If i am right then this line should look like this:

```
chargeTime += Time.deltaTime;
```

Comment: typo in the title suppose to be less than and awake sets it to 0.7

Answer (score 0):

GetButtonUp should not be executed inside of the GetButton statement. The rarity of reaching that code is so low that i am surprised it has ever hit for you at all.

For that matter i would take GetButtonDown out as well.

The execution of code goes in the order as follows:

GetButtonDown (one call)

GetButton (multiple calls)

GetButtonUp (one call)

so you can see that GetButtonDown calls *before* GetButton, therefore the code wont go into GetButton before hitting GetButtonDown

Comment: thanks for the explanation unfortunately i cant up vote for the lack of reputation so i ll leave with a cheers